# Understanding Google Cloud Platform task required for Job Interview

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nosql

Just to clarify, I'm not really looking for help to solve the task, I just want to understand it as I've never done anything whatsoever in GCP (currently a university student and this is a seasonal job).

So the task is:

"create an API in GCP with a Cloud Function and Node with a connection to a (NoSQL) Cloud Datastore-database (Firestore in Datastore-mode). The table should include customers with certain attributes, and the API should support the methods /getCustomers (returns id and name), and /getCustomer?id (which returns all attributes). Put the code in a Cloud Source Repository, and create a pipeline in Cloud Build with a trigger to operate automatically on every commit/push to the repo."

What I've found so far, by searching and doing stuff in Google Cloud Console, I can create one or several tables in BigQuery (for the customers) and then call them from a Cloud Function which responds to a trigger, though I'm unsure what trigger since they said "every commit/push"?

But it feels like I'm missing something... Am I supposed to create a web app using App Engine and store the data i Cloud Firestore (Serverless NoSQL database)?

Any help to clarify this would be golden, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger being referred to there does not have anything to do with Cloud Functions.  It's talking about Cloud Build.  You will need to learn how to set it up so that a build and deployment to Cloud Functions happens automatically whenever code is pushed to Cloud Source Repository.  This is covered in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/integrating-with-cloud-build).

> You can configure Cloud Build to automatically build a new image any time a user pushes a change to files stored in Cloud Source Repositories. Events that initiate automatic builds are called build triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll have a look in Cloud Build then

Answer (score 0):

You must learn several services first:

- Cloud Functions
- Datastore (now Firestore)
- Source Repository
- Cloud Build

If you are an experienced developer and have other cloud experience, you can learn the basics of those services in a day or two.

If you are a beginner, maybe a week for each service - maybe a lot longer.

Then you need to select a language and framework for the API. Don't forget how to authenticate in the cloud - user accounts, service accounts, ADC, etc.

If I was hiring an intern with limited experience with the goal of teaching/training, your project would take a month with a good mentor.

Comment: So, here's the thing. During the initial interview, I made it very clear that I don't have any experience in GCP (or any other cloud service for that matter) but that I had started doing the Google Cloud Learning Paths and begun learning about Cloud Functions and Firestore.

The interviewer then said that was unnecessary and the only thing he wanted to see was that I solved the problem, even if it meant just looking up a tutorial and following the steps, the learning will come along eventually.

The issue is, I don't really understand the problem or what to look for in particular...

Comment: @OscardB - interesting interviewing style. Maybe he is testing your Google search abilities. There are lots of Google Cloud tutorials. However, being a copy-and-paste developer is not what I want on my team even for interns.

Comment: I actually believe so as well. The task was more of a "try out this and let's see how far you can come with zero experience". I'm not sure if he's actually expecting me to do the whole task or just try out some stuff and get something I can show.

Comment: If he is asking you to do that task on your own time, find another job opening. Legitimate/ethical companies do not ask for free labor even in interviews. I expect interns to be smart, motivated, understand how to research problems, and know when to ask for help. Let's close this thread as these comments are off-topic on Stack Overflow.